# Filling the upper triangle of a mtrix in r

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I have 3 vectors as such:

```
 p
            [,1]
[1,] 0.002715955
[2,] 0.004460214
[3,] 0.006855524
[4,] 0.007438570
[5,] 0.042657555
```

```
q
          [,1]
[1,] 0.9972840
[2,] 0.9955398
[3,] 0.9931445
[4,] 0.9925614
[5,] 0.9573424
```

```
f
            [,1]
[1,] 0.008364157
[2,] 0.013058930
[3,] 0.019131397
[4,] 0.020559785
[5,] 0.090786054
```

I want to perform the following operation so as to obtain the var-cov matrix (which fills only the upper triangle of the matrix)

```
v_ij <- p_i*q_j/(n*f_i*f_j); 1<=i<=j<=n
```

Where n is the number of observations(here 5). so I wrote the following code to perform the code

```
v_ij <- matrix(nrow=length(p), ncol=length(p))
for(i in 1:nrow(p)){
  for(j in 1:nrow(q)){
    if(i==j){
      diag(v_ij) <- p[i]*q[j]/(f[i]*f[j])
    }
  }
}
```

This code was only able to fill the diagonal but I didn't which function could fill the upper part of the matrix for i

Comment: Have you heard of `?upper.tri`?

Comment: Yes but when I used it it didn't fill the upper part of my matrix. It says function not found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `tcrossprod` + `lower.tri`, e.g.,

```
v <- tcrossprod(p,q)/tcrossprod(f)/5
v[lower.tri(v)] <- 0
```

such that

```
> v
           [,1]  [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]
[1,] 0.04444444 0.050 0.05333333 0.05555556 0.05714286
[2,] 0.00000000 0.075 0.08000000 0.08333333 0.08571429
[3,] 0.00000000 0.000 0.09600000 0.10000000 0.10285714
[4,] 0.00000000 0.000 0.00000000 0.11111111 0.11428571
[5,] 0.00000000 0.000 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.12244898
```

**DATA**

```
p <- matrix(1:5,nrow = 5,ncol = 1)
q <- matrix(2:6,nrow = 5,ncol = 1)
f <- matrix(3:7,nrow = 5,ncol = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `upper.tri()` as suggested to produce the upper part if that is all you need. The `cov()` function produces the full symmetric matrix:

```
X <- matrix(rnorm(15), ncol=3)
vcov <- cov(X)
```

If you run

```
vcov[upper.tri(vcov, diag=TRUE)]
```

then you only extract the elements but return them as a vector, but

```
vcov*upper.tri(vcov, diag=TRUE)
```

will give you what you want.

```
> X <- matrix(rnorm(15), ncol=3)
> vcov <- cov(X)
> vcov[upper.tri(vcov, diag=TRUE)]
[1] 0.2698385 0.2844101 0.9375529 0.1457635 0.0223076 0.1626811
> vcov*upper.tri(vcov, diag=TRUE)
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 0.2698385 0.2844101 0.1457635
[2,] 0.0000000 0.9375529 0.0223076
[3,] 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.1626811
```

Comment: the problem is that the length of the var-cov matrix should be of the same size as n(the number of observations). This is from an article and I should perform this arithmetic for that.